# Spring NullPointerException despite the relevant annotations used

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, vaadin

I'm trying to do simple login in `vaadin` but when I'm trying login I got the `NullPointerException`. Don't know why my `@autowired` object is not created. I've got the `@Component` annotation on `CustomerService`. Checked the SQL statements, they are ok I suppose. I tried also to remove customer variable and use just service method but the result was the same...

CustomerService code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Customer> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT id, first_name, last_name, email, phoneNumber, login, password FROM customers",
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Customer(
                        rs.getLong("id"),
                        rs.getString("first_name"),
                        rs.getString("last_name"),
                        rs.getString("email"),
                        rs.getString("phoneNumber"),
                        rs.getString("login"),
                        rs.getString("password")));
    }

    public Customer find(String login, String password){
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, email, phoneNumber, login, password FROM customers WHERE login='"
                + login + "' AND password='" + password + "'", Customer.class);
    }

    public void create(Customer customer){
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                "INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name, email, phoneNumber, login, password) VALUES ('"+
                        customer.getFirstName() + "','"+ customer.getLastName()+ "','"+ customer.getEmail()+ "','" +
                        customer.getPhoneNumber() +"','" + customer.getLogin() + "','" + customer.getPassword()+"')");
    }
}
```

Login code:

```
import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringView;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@SpringView(name = "LoginView")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements View{

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService service;

    private Customer customer;

    private TextField login;
    private PasswordField password;
    private Button loginBtn;
    private Button registerBtn;

    protected void init() {
        login = new TextField("Login");
        password = new PasswordField("Password");
        loginBtn = new Button("Sign in");
        registerBtn = new Button("Register");
        HorizontalLayout buttons = new HorizontalLayout(loginBtn, registerBtn);
        loginBtn.addClickListener((Button.ClickListener) clickEvent -> login());
        registerBtn.addClickListener((Button.ClickListener) clickEvent -> register());
        this.addComponents(login, password, buttons);
        this.setComponentAlignment(login, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);
        this.setComponentAlignment(password, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);
        this.setComponentAlignment(buttons, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);
    }

    private void login(){
        customer = service.find(login.getValue(), password.getValue());  // <== Here I got Null Exception
        if(customer==null){
            Window popup = new Window();
            popup.setContent(new Label("User not found!"));
            popup.setVisible(true);
            popup.center();
            getUI().addWindow(popup);
        } else {
            getUI().setContent(new BookView(customer));
        }
    }
    private void register(){
        Window popup = new Window();
        popup.setContent(new RegisterView());
        popup.setVisible(true);
        popup.center();
        getUI().addWindow(popup);
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent viewChangeEvent) {
        init();
    }

    LoginView(){
        init();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

MainUI class:

```
@SpringUI
public class MainUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

        setContent(new LoginView());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get NullPointerException? I mean which line?

Comment: I think @Alex Roig's answer is right. You have to make sure the `init()` method to be called. Just annotate it by `@PostConstruct`

Comment: @Zico yeah but look at my comment to his answer

Comment: @Zico because this View need to be initialized in vaadin UI firstly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is caused by the way that you initialise the view. If you make a `new` Spring will not be aware of this and the dependencies will not be injected. If you want to create a new instance on runtime, you can do that using the `ApplicationContext`. Alternatively, if you need a single instance, you can autowire the dependency directly. Change your MainUI as follows:

```
@SpringUI
public class MainUI extends UI {
    @Autowired
    LoginView loginView;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

        setContent(loginView);
    }
}
```

In `LoginView` Class, you don't need the constructor and you can annotate the `init()` method with `@PostConstruct` so that it gets called just after initialization.

```
@SpringComponent
@Scope("prototype")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements View{

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService service;

    private Customer customer;

    private TextField login;
    private PasswordField password;
    private Button loginBtn;
    private Button registerBtn;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        login = new TextField("Login");
        password = new PasswordField("Password");
        loginBtn = new Button("Sign in");
        registerBtn = new Button("Register");
        HorizontalLayout buttons = new HorizontalLayout(loginBtn, registerBtn);
        loginBtn.addClickListener((Button.ClickListener) clickEvent -> login());
        registerBtn.addClickListener((Button.ClickListener) clickEvent -> register());
        this.addComponents(login, password, buttons);
        this.setComponentAlignment(login, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);
        this.setComponentAlignment(password, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);
        this.setComponentAlignment(buttons, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);
    }

    private void login(){
        customer = service.find(login.getValue(), password.getValue());
        if(customer==null){
            Window popup = new Window();
            popup.setContent(new Label("User not found!"));
            popup.setVisible(true);
            popup.center();
            getUI().addWindow(popup);
        } else {
            getUI().setContent(new BookView(customer));
        }
    }
    private void register(){
        Window popup = new Window();
        popup.setContent(new RegisterView());
        popup.setVisible(true);
        popup.center();
        getUI().addWindow(popup);
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent viewChangeEvent) {
        //init();
        //This init can be removed because with the current scope a new instance will be returned every time
    }

}
```

Comment: well, I can't  remove constructor because I need to initiate it when UI starts, gonna update the question to show you what I mean

Comment: After doing changes in your code I've got "no active views"

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginView': Scope 'vaadin-view' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active view

Comment: As you're not using `SpringNavigator` you don't need to implement the `View` in `LoginView`. Also, you can autowire without the need of the ApplicationContext. You'll get an instance of the layout

Comment: Remove the `@SpringView(name = "LoginView")` and set `@SpringComponent` and `@Scope("prototype")` from the `LoginView`